# how to save TextformField data in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I basically have 2 main screens in my app:

1. main menu - it contains all the pages of my app and i can navigate too those pages from here.
2. main menu item page - this page contains dynamic multi-forms.
   When i create multiple forms and fill input in text fields and press save i want to save the data of multiple forms so i can use that somewhere else,
   and when i go back to main menu and come again to menu item page i want all the forms and that data to be there in text fields.
   my problem is when i go back and come again to menu item page, all multiform are lost and all the data is also lost.

[image]
[image]
[image]

if the form is saved then after navigating to different pages the forms and data should remain on the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of many data storing methods.

- You can save to database such as mySql
- You can save to a json file
- You can use the **shared_preferences** package
- Hive database
- ...

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to locally store the data using [shared preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

```
// Pass your controller.text here
saveToPhone(String name) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      preferences.setString('name', name);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
 
// Get your data while your app opens using this function
  getFromPhone() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      return preferences.getString('name');
 
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Find the complete example of the above [here](https://www.flutterdecode.com/flutter-shared-preferences-example/#:%7E:text=Flutter%20SharedPreferences%20Example%3A%20The%20Simplest%20Way%20to%20store,the%20data%20...%207%20Step7%3A%20Full%20code%20)

Answer (score 0):

Create a model class of form,
on click event of save

- you can store value using controller to model class and then access
  it on another screen
  OR
- save data in **local database SQLite**
- **shared_pref**